# after sync gradle all layout change in build

Tags: android, android-layout

i was working in android studio with any problem, but suddenly after opening "lint warning in layout" after click on its suggest Gradle synced and all my layout has been change in output APK but all layout in android studio has not any problem .please see my attached image .
why this problem occurred ?

this is my xml code :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="fragments.AboutHimmelFragment"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="167dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/headerabout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_telegramchannel"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="129dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.076"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icontelegram" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="درباره هیمل"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ln_Call1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/BackGeneralGreen"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView66"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="09122831879"
                android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:background="@color/WhiteColor"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView133"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconphone" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/BackGeneralGreen"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView666"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="021-55741239"
                android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:background="@color/WhiteColor"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1333"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconphone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/BackGeneralGreen"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView65"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="09101596788"
                android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:background="@color/WhiteColor"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconphone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Ln_SendMail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/BackGeneralGreen"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="info@himmel.com"
                android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:background="@color/WhiteColor"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView132"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_email" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="467dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconabout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_Content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="14sp"
        android:text="@string/AboutHimmel"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i clean and remove apk in emulator more than 3 times but never thing has not been changed ! any one can help me ?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your ConstraintLayout isn't setup correctly. Hint: The preview does not always match the actual screen. You have a red `9+` error that you need to fix in the preview window

Answer (score 0):

I found reason ! this happened because of list line :

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

when i change 0dp to match-parent its work fine. but yet i dont know why this doesn't show in preview !

Answer (score -1):

Try, go to Files>Invalidate Cache/Restart